# Failure of perturbation theory in the thermodynamic limit

Tags: statistical-mechanics, hamiltonian, perturbation-theory

I can't really understand why one says the perturbation methods in the Hamiltonian contest ( so theorem's like KAM ) will fail in the thermodynamic limit. More precisely I can't understand the following sentence:

"the classical methods (of Hamiltonian perturbation theory) do not apply in the thermodynamic limit
(namely, when the number N of degrees of freedom tends to infinity and the
energy divided by N, the specific energy, remains constant), and so, classical perturbation theory as it stands is useless in the frame of statistical
mechanics. Essentially, the reason for the failure is that in the classical theory one pretends to control all initial data, even the ones that should be
obviously considered exceptional (think, for instance, of the data for which
all the energy is concentrated on a single degree of freedom). On the other
hand, for the aims of statistical mechanics, only mean values with respect to
a given probability measure are relevant, without the necessity of controlling
all individual motions, so that a weaker approach is sufficient."

Can somebody explains me the above argument in more precisely way?

Comment: Could you add which part of the sentence you didn't understand?

Comment: I think that the part "the reason for the failure is that in the classical theory one pretends to control all initial data, even the ones that should be obviously considered exceptional (think, for instance, of the data for which all the energy is concentrated on a single degree of freedom)." .How is this relate with the classical theorem like KAM?

Comment: The usage of Classical and statistical mechanics are very different, in SM we assume to not know the exact microstate of the particle. The theory for CM does not stay valid in the thermodynamic limit. Think of the phase space in CM, the orbit will be quasi-periodic for a quasi-integrable model (KAM). The point is, in SM the ergodic hypothesis is that the system will eventually pass throughout all energetic valuable phase space.